# Laravel: Unknown column $parameter in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, parameters

I have troubles with using a parameter in a DB query and parameter binding in Laravel.

I get this error:

> Error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'on clause'"

This is the part of a query:

```
->join('foo AS f1', function($join) use ($bar)
      {
           $join->on('f1.foo', '=', 'f2.foo')
                ->on('f1.bar', '=', $bar);
      })
```

If I do this instead, it works:

```
->on('f1.bar', '=', DB::raw($bar));
```

What's the solution to this? I would like to use parameter binding for this as well of course. However, when I do:

```
->on('f1.bar', '=', ':bar', ['bar' => $bar]);
```

I get this:

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 196:
> Array to string conversion

Comment: are you sure that the problem is only given snippet ?

Comment: yes, I got the answer. only the parameter binding is still not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you connecting two tables with join you must specify the column names ($bar must be equal to column name string). So if you want to send some parameters data you must use `where` instead `on`.

```
->join('foo AS f1', function($join) use ($bar)
      {
           $join->on('f1.foo', '=', 'f2.foo')
                ->where('f1.bar', '=', $bar);
      })
```

Comment: ah yeah sure, thanks! still get the Array to string conversion for parameter binding though.